# Android - Using AlarmManager or Timer on Service when fairly heavy task hight frequence periodic

Tags: android, service, gps, alarmmanager

I'm newbie on android and really thank you for your attention.

My case is an app that have to check the gps every 10s (or 30s, not fixed yet) and compare to data saved on local db, after that, it maybe send gps to server and get response, save data to local db.

I think it's a fairly heavy job and excute hight frequence.
So could anyone tell me should choose service with timer or using alarmManager?

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: use alarm manger with service or intent service. If you have to do task more frequent then use JobSchedular

Comment: use a [`STICY_SERVICE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) in `onStartCommand` do a network call and send latitude and longitude then `onLocationChanged`  do a network call and send latitude and longitude